# What is the limit of this exponential sum? It's like an infinite geometric series, but where the ratio approaches zero as the terms increase

Tags: limits, summation, exponential-function

The function is this:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{T}{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} e^{krT/n}
$$

Where $r, T \in \mathbb{R}, r < 0, T > 0$

It seems like its related to the sum of a geometric series, but it's not quite that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is exactly a geometric series
with the ratio being
$e^{rT/n}$.
Since this ratio goes to $1$ as
$n \to \infty$,
the sum diverges.

Here are the details.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} e^{krT/n}
&=\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \left(e^{rT/n}\right)^k\\
&=\dfrac{1-\left(e^{rT/n}\right)^n}{1-e^{rT/n}}\\
&=\dfrac{1-e^{rT}}{1-e^{rT/n}}\\
&\to\dfrac{1-e^{rT}}{1-(1+rT/n)}
\qquad e^x \to 1+x \text{ as } x \to 0\\
&=\dfrac{1-e^{rT}}{-rT/n}\\
&=-n\dfrac{1-e^{rT}}{rT}\\
&\to \infty
\qquad\text{as } n \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: I had forgotten the T/n factor, which is necessary for it to not diverge. The question has been updated with that factor, I think your simplification to remove the summation still applies, but then the question becomes about the limit of T/n, i'll take a look and see if the result right before your diverging works if I multiply it by T/n.

Comment: Your answer is right to the question I meant to ask if I multiply your last result by T/n, and then it converges. I'm marking your answer as good, but if you have a chance, could you fix it with the constant factor so that someone else looking will find the right answer?

Comment: I had personally just gotten to the limit from replacing the summation with the partial geometric summation, but I didn't know the trick about e^x going to 1 + x, thank you for the detailed working out.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the limit at the front, it is exactly the sum of a geometric series.

$\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n-1} e^{\frac {krt}{n}} = \frac {1 - e^{rT}}{1-e^{\frac {rT}{n}}}$

And as $n$ goes to infinity we see that the result diverges.

Alternatively, if we look at the summand, we see that it does not approach 0 at the limit, and that is a requirement for convergence.

Comment: When I first posted the question, I was missing the fraction at the front of the summation, You correctly answered the question I asked at first. I noticed the error and tried to fix it quickly after posting, but you and marty were too quick for me. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

With the factor in front, this is a Riemann sum

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\exp\left(r\frac{kT}{n}\right)\cdot\frac{T}{n} \equiv \int_0^{T}\exp(rx)\:dx = \frac{\exp(rT)-1}{r}$$